# Creating function to remove certain elements from a nested list

Tags: python-3.x, list

:
    '''
    To complete.
    '''

````
When I run ```eliminate_elements([['N', 'L'], ['G', 'N','L'], ['N', 'B']], ['N','L'])```, I want the output to be ```[[],[, ['G', 'L'], ['B']]``` Why is 'L' not removed when it clearly is an element in to_eliminate?
Please note that I do not want built in python functions to do this, I have to create my own function that does not rely on any outside modules or functions.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# your code goes here

def eliminate_elements(my_list, to_eliminate):
    '''
    To complete.
    '''

    for sub_list in my_list:
        for i in to_eliminate:
            if i in sub_list:
                occu = sub_list.count(i)
                for _ in range(occu):
                    sub_list.remove(i)

    return my_list  

print(eliminate_elements( [['N', 'L'], ['G', 'N', 'L'], ['N', 'B']],  ['N', 'L']))
```

output

```
[[], ['G'], ['B']]
```